# Bootstrap 3 - dropdown login form without caret and upper rounded borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded Bootstrap 3.0.3 (clicked the "Download Bootstrap" button from the home page) and used this code to make a login form come from a dropdown.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="register" data-toggle="dropdown">Register <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 400px">
                <form id="register-form" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                    <!--(form goes here)-->
                </form>
            </div> <!-- /dropdown-menu -->
        </li> <!-- /dropdown -->
        <!--(here goes another dropdown)-->
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar-collapse -->
```

Rounded corners only show at the bottom and I couldn't manage to make the caron appear. After a while I checked here and found out that I had a few lines missing in my Bootstrap CSS file - namely these lines:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #CCC;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: '';
}

.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  content: '';
}
```

I added these lines to a second CSS. Of course they make the caron appear on the left hand side of the dropdown, but I'd like it to appear on the right. I assume there are probably a few more lines missing in my CSS (did the caron recently become obsolete for Bootstrap?).

I'd also like to correct the problem about top corners not appearing rounded.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us1oC.png

Comment: i think you have please share your full source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `left` to `right` in the CSS

**Change this**

```
 left: 10px;
```

**to this**

```
 right: 10px; /*Adjust the value as per your need*/
```